# Excel range pasted into Outlook using VBA is blank/white

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

This code will capture a range in Excel, export it, then embed it into the body of an email, along with text.

The image is appearing white/blank unless I have the worksheet open in front. I tried adding code to maximize the window and this doesn't work.

It only works when I run it one line at a time.

```vb
Public reportInterval As String
Public startBody As String
Public digitalBody As String
Public socroBody As String
Public fleetBody As String
Public loopBody As String
Public morningOrDay As String
Public picFile As String
Public picBody As String

Sub emailPic()

    '===================================================
    ' Export Range as PNG file
    '===================================================
    ' Set Range you want to export to file
    Dim r As Range
    Dim co As ChartObject

    Workbooks(controlWS).Sheets(tempWS).Select

    Set r = Range("A1:R133")

    ' Copy range as picture onto Clipboard
    r.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
    picFile = Environ("Temp") & "\TempExportChart.png"

    ' Create an empty chart with exact size of range copied
    Set co = r.Parent.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=r.Left, Top:=r.Top, Width:=r.Width, Height:=r.Height)
    With co
        ' Paste into chart area, export to file, delete chart.
        .Chart.Paste
        .Chart.Export picFile
        .Delete
    End With

End Sub


Sub sendMail()

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim objOutlook  As Object
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim objEmail    As Object
    Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    reportInterval = ""
    Call emailPic
    Call intervalFinder
    Call morningOrDayFinder
    Call htmlEmailBody

    picBody = "<img src=""" & picFile & """ style=""width:304px;height:228px"">"

    With objEmail
    .Display
        .SentOnBehalfOfName =
        .To =
        .CC = 
        .Recipients.ResolveAll
        .Subject = "Intraday Report: " & reportInterval
        .HTMLBody = HTMLBody & startBody & digitalBody & socroBody & fleetBody & loopBody _
        & picBody
    End With

    Set objEmail = Nothing:    Set objOutlook = Nothing

ErrHandler:
    '
End Sub
```

Comment: Saellie, you wrote that the code works fine when running a line at a time. Maybe the code runs faster than it take the chart object to become fully processed. So, maybe try adding a delay to your code where the chart is being pasted, exported, and deleted. E.g., ```Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)``` will add a 5-second delay. Hope, this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck with adding delays :(

Comment: Saellie, maybe also try adding ```DoEvents``` into your code.

Comment: @Saellie, just insert ``.Chart.Parent.Select`` before ``.Chart.Paste``

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the picture file is being created as blank via the chart object. I have previously found issues using chart objects to save pictures adding borders where I don't want them so I use publishers functions instead to save pictures. This does require a reference to be added.

> Updated function to save the picture (you will need to re-edit back to the sheet you want to export)

```
Sub emailPic()
    ' Requires reference: Microsoft Publisher x.x Object Library
    
    '===================================================
    ' Export Range as PNG file
    '===================================================
    Dim r As Range
    Dim picFile As String: picFile = Environ("Temp") & "\TempExport.png"

    If Dir(picFile) <> "" Then Kill picFile

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set r = .Range("A1:R133")
        r.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap    ' Copy range as picture onto Clipboard
    End With

    Dim PubDoc As New Publisher.Document
    PubDoc.Pages(1).Shapes.Paste
    PubDoc.Pages(1).Shapes(1).SaveAsPicture _
        PbResolution:=pbPictureResolutionCommercialPrint_300dpi, _
        Filename:=picFile
    PubDoc.Close
End Sub
```