# How to use VBA in Excel to save data as an image

Tags: excel, vba, image, export

is there a way to use VBA to export values of variables into an image file? Specifically, I have for each x and y position on a 2 dimensional map a value of either 0 or 1 and want to visualize this as a simple black and white image.

The only way I can think of that might somehow work (I'm pretty new to VBA programming) is to write the data in a worksheet and use conditionally formating, so if the value is 0 then the cell is black, if 1 then white and then after making the individual cells quadratic in size save the range using something like Range.CopyPicture. But I hope there's a better way to do this.

Comment: I think your idea is feasible and I am not aware about a method in VBA to create and manipulate bitmaps. Any reason you want to use VBA for that (if you don't want to write it into an excel sheet)? Where is the data from (a file?) and in which format?

Comment: You can export a range as a picture going via Publisher (but you would need to format the data as you want it exported visually) as per: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69078073/3688861

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

I don't quite know how your data is laid out, but I wrote some `Sub`s that will write a `bitmap` file based on two-dimensional arrays. I chose `bitmap` because it has a very simple binary layout and you can then proceed to work with it with almost any image editing/processing software.

### Black and White

Pass a two-dimensional `Boolean` array to this `Sub`:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Type BITMAPFILEHEADER
    bfType As Integer
    bfSize As Long
    bfReserved1 As Integer
    bfReserved2 As Integer
    bfOffBits As Long
End Type

Private Type BITMAPINFOHEADER
    biSize As Long
    biWidth As Long
    biHeight As Long
    biPlanes As Integer
    biBitCount As Integer
    biCompression As Long
    biSizeImage As Long
    biXPelsPerMeter As Long
    biYPelsPerMeter As Long
    biClrUsed As Long
    biClrImportant As Long
End Type

Sub CreateBWBitmap(arr() As Boolean, fileName As String)
    Dim width As Long, height As Long
    height = UBound(arr, 1) + 1
    width = UBound(arr, 2) + 1
    
    Dim bmpFileHeader As BITMAPFILEHEADER
    Dim bmpInfoHeader As BITMAPINFOHEADER
    
    'Initialize BITMAPFILEHEADER
    bmpFileHeader.bfType = &H4D42 ' "BM" in hexadecimal
    bmpFileHeader.bfOffBits = 62 ' 14 for file header, 40 for info header, 8 for color table
    bmpFileHeader.bfSize = bmpFileHeader.bfOffBits + ((((width + 31) \ 32) * 4) * height)
    
    'Initialize BITMAPINFOHEADER
    bmpInfoHeader.biSize = 40
    bmpInfoHeader.biWidth = width
    bmpInfoHeader.biHeight = height
    bmpInfoHeader.biPlanes = 1
    bmpInfoHeader.biBitCount = 1 ' Black and white
    bmpInfoHeader.biCompression = 0 ' Uncompressed
    bmpInfoHeader.biSizeImage = 0
    bmpInfoHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0
    bmpInfoHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0
    bmpInfoHeader.biClrUsed = 2
    bmpInfoHeader.biClrImportant = 2
    
    'Create color table (black and white)
    Dim colorTable(1) As Long
    colorTable(0) = vbBlack
    colorTable(1) = vbWhite
    
    'Create the pixel data
    Dim rowData As Long
    rowData = (((width + 31) \ 32) * 4)
    Dim pixelData() As Byte
    ReDim pixelData(rowData * height - 1)
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, bit As Long, bytePos As Long, bitPos As Long
    For i = 0 To height - 1
        For j = 0 To width - 1
            bit = IIf(arr(height - 1 - i, j), 1, 0)
            bytePos = (rowData * i) + (j \ 8)
            bitPos = 7 - (j Mod 8)
            pixelData(bytePos) = pixelData(bytePos) Or (bit * (2 ^ bitPos))
        Next j
    Next i
    
    'Write the data to the file
    Dim f As Integer
    f = FreeFile
    Open fileName For Binary Access Write As #f
        Put #f, , bmpFileHeader
        Put #f, , bmpInfoHeader
        Put #f, , colorTable(0)
        Put #f, , colorTable(1)
        Put #f, , pixelData
    Close #f
End Sub
```

This example sub will create a 10 * 10 checkboard pattern .bmp file on your desktop:

```vb
Sub TestCreateBWBitmap()
    Dim arr(9, 9) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    'Fill with checkboard pattern
    For i = 0 To 9
        For j = 0 To 9
            arr(i, j) = ((i + j) Mod 2 = 0)
        Next j
    Next i
    
    CreateBWBitmap arr, CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\" & "test.bmp"
End Sub
```

### Full Color:

To create a full-color BMP, pass a two-dimensional `Long` array containing RGB values to this function: (again with the private types for faster copy-paste)

```vb
Private Type BITMAPFILEHEADER
    bfType As Integer
    bfSize As Long
    bfReserved1 As Integer
    bfReserved2 As Integer
    bfOffBits As Long
End Type

Private Type BITMAPINFOHEADER
    biSize As Long
    biWidth As Long
    biHeight As Long
    biPlanes As Integer
    biBitCount As Integer
    biCompression As Long
    biSizeImage As Long
    biXPelsPerMeter As Long
    biYPelsPerMeter As Long
    biClrUsed As Long
    biClrImportant As Long
End Type

Sub CreateColorBitmap(arr() As Long, fileName As String)
    Dim height As Long: height = UBound(arr, 1) + 1
    Dim width As Long:  width = UBound(arr, 2) + 1
    
    Dim bmpFileHeader As BITMAPFILEHEADER
    Dim bmpInfoHeader As BITMAPINFOHEADER
    
    'Initialize BITMAPFILEHEADER
    bmpFileHeader.bfType = &H4D42 '"BM" in hexadecimal
    bmpFileHeader.bfOffBits = 54 '14 for file header, 40 for info header
    bmpFileHeader.bfSize = bmpFileHeader.bfOffBits + (width * height * 3)
    
    'Initialize BITMAPINFOHEADER
    bmpInfoHeader.biSize = 40
    bmpInfoHeader.biWidth = width
    bmpInfoHeader.biHeight = height
    bmpInfoHeader.biPlanes = 1
    bmpInfoHeader.biBitCount = 24 'True color (24-bit)
    bmpInfoHeader.biCompression = 0 'Uncompressed
    bmpInfoHeader.biSizeImage = 0
    bmpInfoHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0
    bmpInfoHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0
    bmpInfoHeader.biClrUsed = 0
    bmpInfoHeader.biClrImportant = 0
    
    'Create the pixel data
    Dim rowData As Long: rowData = width * 3
    
    'Add padding for DWORD alignment
    If rowData Mod 4 <> 0 Then rowData = rowData + 4 - (rowData Mod 4)
    
    Dim pixelData() As Byte: ReDim pixelData(rowData * height - 1)
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 0 To height - 1
        For j = 0 To width - 1
            Dim color As Long:   color = arr(height - 1 - i, j)
            Dim bytePos As Long: bytePos = rowData * i + j * 3

            pixelData(bytePos) = (color And &HFF0000) \ &H10000 'Blue
            pixelData(bytePos + 1) = (color And &HFF00&) \ &H100 'Green
            pixelData(bytePos + 2) = color And &HFF 'Red
        Next j
    Next i
    
    'Write the data to the file
    Dim f As Integer: f = FreeFile
    Open fileName For Binary Access Write As #f
        Put #f, , bmpFileHeader
        Put #f, , bmpInfoHeader
        Put #f, , pixelData
    Close #f
End Sub
```

I created an example sub that makes a BMP containing a color-, brightness- and saturation gradient:

```vb
Sub CreateRainbowGradientBitmap()
    Const width As Long = 1000
    Const height As Long = 1000
    Dim arr() As Long
    ReDim arr(height - 1, width - 1)
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim h As Double, s As Double, l As Double
    
    For i = 0 To height - 1
        For j = 0 To width - 1
            h = 360# * (j / (width - 1)) ' Hue ranges from 0 to 360
            s = 100 ' Saturation is fixed at 100 for a full gradient
            l = i / (height - 1) * 100 ' Lightness ranges from 0 to 100
    
            arr(i, j) = hslToRgb(h, s, l)
        Next j
    Next i
    
    CreateColorBitmap arr, CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\" & "test.bmp"
End Sub

'adapted from: http://www.easyrgb.com/
Public Function hslToRgb(ByVal hue As Double, _
                         ByVal saturation As Double, _
                         ByVal lightness As Double) As Long
    Dim h As Double: h = hue / 360
    Dim s As Double: s = saturation / 100
    Dim l As Double: l = lightness / 100
    
    If h < 0 Or h > 1 Then Err.Raise 5, "hueToRgb", "Invalid hue value."
    If s < 0 Or s > 1 Then Err.Raise 5, "hueToRgb", "Invalid saturation value."
    If l < 0 Or l > 1 Then Err.Raise 5, "hueToRgb", "Invalid lightness value."
    
    If s = 0 Then
        Dim red As Double: red = l * 255
        Dim green As Double: green = l * 255
        Dim blue As Double: blue = l * 255
    Else
        Dim x2 As Double
        If l < 0.5 Then
            x2 = l * (1 + s)
        Else
            x2 = (l + s) - (l * s)
        End If
        Dim x1 As Double: x1 = 2 * l - x2
        
        red = 255 * hueToRgb(x1, x2, h + (1 / 3))
        green = 255 * hueToRgb(x1, x2, h)
        blue = 255 * hueToRgb(x1, x2, h - (1 / 3))
     End If
     hslToRgb = RGB(red, green, blue)
End Function

'Helper function for hslToRgb.
'adapted from: http://www.easyrgb.com/
Private Function hueToRgb(a As Double, b As Double, h As Double) As Double
    If h < 0 Then h = h + 1
    If h > 1 Then h = h - 1
    
    If (6 * h < 1) Then
        hueToRgb = a + (b - a) * 6 * h
    ElseIf (2 * h < 1) Then
        hueToRgb = b
    ElseIf (3 * h < 2) Then
        hueToRgb = a + (b - a) * ((2 / 3) - h) * 6
    Else
        hueToRgb = a
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Nice. +1. Consider using ```vbWhite``` and ```vbBlack``` constants.

Comment: Since this works now really well with my data I was wondering if it would be possible to not use a boolean data array but an array which contains additional information (let's say numbers 0 to 9) for each pixel and use this value for color coding of the resulting bitmap.

Comment: @MatthiasHiermaier, that is possible for sure, if I have time I can add it to the answer tomorrow. Maybe you can already figure it out before that :)

Comment: @GWD, I tried for several hours now, but I just cannot bring it to work. I would very much apprechiate your help if you can find the time.